# Add custom variables to shipping method

Tags: event-observer, onepage-checkout

I currently have "free shipping" (which it's ok).

I want to add below the variables:

- Frequency (once per week, per month, etc).
- Day and hour of delivery (Mon to Sat, etc).

So after the shipping method page is completed I also have a delivery frequency.

I've tried observers but it seems nothing observes shipping methods. Adding a custom shipping method is not an option since these variables should be apart from "free shipping" method. Also, the variables should be in the shipping method page.

So far i've inserted the html code in /design/frontend/.../giftmessage/inline.phtml, since that page is called in shipping method and (although this is not part of a gift message) couldn't find a better place to place it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add new fields (frequency & Day/hour of delivery) in design/frontend/../checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

Add condition inside for loop

```
   if($code == 'freeshipping_freeshipping'){
//Add your custom fields here
}
```

Than add observer event as below code:

```
    <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
        <observers>
            <shipnote>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>Class_Name_where_observer_resides</class>
                <method>checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method</method>
            </shipnote>
        </observers>
    </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
```

In your method you can add below code:

```
public function checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $firstfieldValue = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParam('first_field_name');

// logic to save data into quote

    }
```

I hope above instruction will help you.